# Weak reference to constans?

Tags: ios, sdk, constants, backwards-compatibility, weak-references

I'm trying to use some library built in XCode 5 to link in some app in XCode 4.
That library has references to constants defined in iOS7 SDK, but not in iOS6 SDK.

So I'm getting this error:

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
   "_CBPeripheralManagerRestoredStateServicesKey", referenced from:**

Is there any way to preserve backward compatibility with XCode 4 and SDK for iOS6?

Comment: `h = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth"); NSString *key = dlsym(h, "CBPeripheralManagerRestoredStateServicesKey");`

Comment: Thank you! Using your tip I've built working function. It's below.

Comment: Yap, sorry, forgot a level of indirection. I'm glad you came to a correct solution yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+ (NSString *)getCoreBluetoothConstantByName:(NSString *)name
    {
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth", RTLD_LOCAL);

if (libHandle != NULL)
    {
    NSString **key = dlsym(libHandle, [name cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

    dlclose(libHandle);

    return [[*key copy] autorelease];
    }

return nil;
}
```